# How is human waste taken care of on commerical aircraft?

Tags: commercial-aviation

Trains, as far as I'm aware, just dump human waste on to their own tracks. There are often warnings like: `DO NOT USE the toilet while the train is stopped at the station` voiced through the PAs or signed up on the walls. [The Daily Mail](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2526535/Train-firms-banned-allowing-utterly-disgusting-toilets-flush-sewage-tracks.html#ixzz3SlArr0qL), in 2014 had an article mentioning: `Train companies are to be ordered to adapt their trains to stop dumping sewage on the tracks.`

I always kind of assumed that commercial airliners did the same, but I've never heard any warnings about using the restrooms aside from when the seat-belt sign is on.

- How do commercial airliners take care of human waste?

Comment: At least in my country, also trains don't dump it on the tracks any more. For high speed trains, this would be interesting, especially in a pressure surge when entering a tunnel. All other trains have newer wagons or the wagons got tanks on their last overhaul...

Comment: Most trains in the UK store waste as well. Anything built after perhaps the 80s does. The biggest exception is the Mark 3 coaches used by HST (Intercity 125) trains (the diesel trains running up the east coast to Aberdeen and from London to the west from Paddington). These do fling waste out, which at 125 mph can be unpleasant for track-side workers.

Comment: I don't think they are the only ones. I frequently see what looks like toilet waste round manchester and intercity 125s don't come up here. I guess some of the older DMUs must be dropping toilet waste on the tracks.

Answer (score 3):

Human waste from the lavatories is collected on-board and later [disposed of at the airport after landing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aircraft_lavatory#Lavatory_agents).

[image]
<sup>(Image Source: [WikiMedia Commons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Aircraft_lavatory_service.jpg) - Author: Mnts)</sup>

Check out this related question here on Aviation.SE:
[Where does my pee go when I flush at 35,000 ft?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/2361/572)

Comment: It should also be noted that although planes do use tanks, there is a phenomenom known as "blue ice". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_ice_(precipitation). You probably don't want that falling on your head.