# How does an engine fall off the wing?

Tags: wing, engine

When I was a kid, I remember one day the news on TV said that a passenger airplane lost an engine.  It simply fell off the wing to the ground.  Then they showed the plane (which landed safely) and the bent up engine in some field.

1) How could that happen that an engine simply falls off?  How many bolts are holding the engine up?

2) If it sheared off the wing, why didn't it break the wing with it?

3) Are there any special protocol(s) for missing engine v. disabled engine?

In addition to what I saw as a kid, [this](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/travel/travel_news/article-3273932/747-plane-engine-snaps-Iran-flight-no-injuries.html) happened last year

Comment: Related: [Have jet engines ever “Sheared” off?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/24935/have-jet-engines-ever-sheared-off)

Comment: Whoever is voting to close this, I wouldn't say it is a duplicate because in that question I am asking for incidents where engine-off happened and not how engine-off "works". None of the answers there would answer this question.

Comment: The pylons are actually made so that if they have a problem, such as vibration that could affect the rest of the plane they will fall off do they don't take the wing with them. Loss of an engine can be dealt with but a damaged wing is a much more serous problem

Comment: [Related to the 3rd question, specifically regarding the fuel lines.](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/24954/1696)