# Why do civil aviation aircraft not routinely carry missile defense systems?

Tags: safety, military, commercial-aviation

With all the incidents with civil aircraft and missiles, why do civil aircraft not carry flares and other defensive measures by default? If official aircraft carry them it is technically possible to fit them, isn’t it? With the possible fallout and the enormous loss of life, why do air defense systems allow the operators to target civil aircraft in the first place?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why don't airliners carry radar jamming technology or missile counter measures?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/7768/why-dont-airliners-carry-radar-jamming-technology-or-missile-counter-measures)

Comment: See also https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/66587/why-dont-commercial-aircraft-adopt-a-slightly-more-seaplane-like-design-to-allo

Comment: "All the incidents"? I count 39 in over 80 years. Of those, 1 missed the target, so a missile defense system was not necessary, 8 were attacked with guns, 1 with artillery, so a missile defense system wouldn't have helped, 3 were attacked on the ground, 1 is only rumoured but not proven to be hit by a missile, 1 was an "unknown projectile", several were light aircraft that don't have the power and space to install missile defense systems, 2 stretch the definition of "civilian" (they were Cuban-Americans illegally violating Cuban airspace to drop anti-government propaganda leaflets).

Comment: And for why missile systems allow civil aircraft to be targeted, 1) How do you reliably tell the difference between military & civil aircraft? 2) If there WAS some reliable way - say transponder codes for a simple example - wouldn't anyone wanting to carry out a sneak attack simply masquerade as a civil aircraft? 3) There are circumstances, such as a repeat of 9/11, where you might want to shoot down civil aircraft.